# XML Parser using PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have this xml content. I need to get the value from the fullName attribute. I have tried it using lib.xml parser. But it is not working. Could you please help me to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><currentUserDetails firstName="3rdParty" fullName="3rdParty Access" lastName="Access" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="" xmlns=""/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `simplexml`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assuming XML in $x
echo $xml['fullName'];
```

See it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/7KVHcU

Comment: When i assign the $xml['fullName'] to the session variable
 $_SESSION["fullusername"] = $xml['fullName'];
It is displaying as 
 [fullusername] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 3rdParty Access
        )

Comment: @user2118463: cast to string: `$test = (string)$xml['fullName'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlFile   = "http://www.domaine.com/city.xml";

$data      = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);

print_r($data);
```